# Django - Override Default Manager in Admin - InheritanceManager

Tags: python, django, django-model-utils

(This seems to be a common question based on the "Questions that may already have your answer" list, but none of those has helped me.)

I have a several models with multi-table inheritance.

In admin (and later, in the front-end app), I need to have a list of all things in the base class, and also be able to identify which child (or grandchild) class they belong to.

I am trying to use [Inheritance Manager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) for this. No luck so far.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    objects = InheritanceManager()

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = self.model.objects.get_queryset()
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request)
        if ordering:
            qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
        return qs

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name + " entry"


class Person(Entity):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name + " Person"
```

Adding the string "person" and "Entry" is just a test.

Lists of Entities just show `Entry`, even if  is also(actually) a person.

I would like to be able to write into `Entry.__str__` something that would show the final subclass. That way I could get a list of entries and see:

```
Bob (Person)
ABC Co. (Organization)
Great Expectations (Book)
```

Comment: Does `self.__class__.__name__` do the trick?

Comment: Nope. Returns the parent class (Entry) if I'm looking at a list of all Entries.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and found hacks to it one way or another. But it never felt clean.
I ended up using [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)...

> When we store models that inherit from a Project model...
>
> `Project.objects.create(topic="Department Party")
>   ArtProject.objects.create(topic="Painting with Tim", artist="T. Turner")
>   ResearchProject.objects.create(topic="Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor="Dr. Winter")`
>
> ...and want to retrieve all our projects, the subclassed models are returned!
>
> `Project.objects.all()
>       [ <Project:         id 1, topic "Department Party">,
>         <ArtProject:      id 2, topic "Painting with Tim", artist "T. Turner">,
>         <ResearchProject: id 3, topic "Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor "Dr. Winter"> ]`
>
> Using vanilla Django, we get the base class objects, which is rarely what we wanted:
>
> `Project.objects.all()
>       [ <Project: id 1, topic "Department Party">,
>         <Project: id 2, topic "Painting with Tim">,
>         <Project: id 3, topic "Swallow Aerodynamics"> ]`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Looks like it should, but when I follow the instructions in quickstart, and migrate models, I get "Does Not Exist" errors in Admin. Would you be kind enough to do a quick example, or explain how you have done this?

Comment: Even after you went through the https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html section?

Comment: I should have SO reputation points taken away for thinking "Quick Start" would be enough information.

Comment: So I got an admin screen mostly up and running, and I can create a new entry from a single interface, selecting the sub-type as I go --- great.
But I still can't figure out how to do the thing I wanted to do: self.__str__ returning the child class.

Comment: I got it. `polymorphic_list = True` in the admin parent model.